# Registry/directory for software projects?

Tags: directories

We have several projects and each has own resources, like:

- name
- description
- Git/Hg/SVN URLs, important branches / naming convention
- BTS (bug-tracker)
- build pipelines URLs / naming convention
- artifact repositories / naming convention for versions
- test/stage/pre-prod/prod infrastructure URLs (DBs, message pipes, servers, registries, etc)
- inter-project dependencies

I'd like to keep this information in some structural way.

We can start from wiki. But I don't understand how can I search for certain kind of information (like get URLs for all databases or WEB services) without reading all wiki pages...

I am looking for something like openhub.net or directory.fsf.org but with extensible set of fields (not only link to home page and Git).

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) and adjust your question accordingly, then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose a schema for these projects, write them in a simple format (JSON or YAML) and then use those documents to populate a database.

The database can be sql or nosql (mongo, *etc*) and the data can be used to generate web pages for the project, based on templates.

A static site builder like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.org/) would be good for the job